# volume deleted from kvm, but not reflected in centos guest

Tags: virtual-machine, centos, virtualization, linux-kvm

I assigned some volumes to my VM on kvm.
Now I want to remove those volumes. 
I used virsh vol-delete command and deleted those volumes. 
Still from the guest side,  can see those volumes!!!. 
lsblk, fdisk etc is listing those volumes. 
It is not a stale entry. I can even make files on those volumes. I rebooted my guest, but no luck.

list below shows no volumes in the pool now . Only it has boot volumes., but guest is showing already deleted volumes as well!

```
virsh # pool-list
 Name                 State      Autostart 
-------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes       
 pool_1               active     yes       
 vm-images            active     yes       

virsh # vol-list --pool default   --->boot volume
 Name                 Path                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 -------
 GOS_1.qcow2          /var/lib/libvirt/images/GOS_1.qcow2     

virsh # vol-list --pool pool_1   ---> I deleted from this pool
 Name                 Path                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

virsh # vol-list --pool vm-images   --->just vm image backup
 Name                 Path                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-------
 centos70_vdisk.raw   /container/vm-images/centos70_vdisk.raw 

virsh #
```

From my guest:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
 NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0    3G  0 disk  ---ghost partition now
└─sda1            8:1    0    3G  0 part 
sdb               8:16   0   20G  0 disk  ----ghost partition now
sdc               8:32   0   20G  0 disk  ---ghost partition now
sdd               8:48   0    4G  0 disk   --boot 
├─sdd1            8:49   0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sdd2            8:50   0  3.5G  0 part 
  ├─centos-swap 253:0    0  412M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-root 253:1    0  3.1G  0 lvm  /
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]#
```

But I can see from dumpxml command, vm has

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
  <source file='/container/pool/TEST.qcow2'/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev='sdc' bus='scsi'/>
  <alias name='scsi0-0-0-2'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='2'/>
</disk>
```

But no disk in the location.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /container/pool
[root@localhost ~]# ls -a /container/pool
.  ..
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutdown guest (destroy). and then try start again.

In *nix generally when removing opened file it removed from directory, but actually removed from disk when nobody keep it opened.

Comment: I restarted the vm from guest now, Its not booting up.


    [root@localhost ~]# virsh start GOS_1
    error: Failed to start domain GOS_1
     error: Cannot access storage file '/container/pool/TEST.qcow2' (as 
     uid:107, gid:107): No such file or directory


I thinks its domain xml already has those removed disk and when I tried to start the guest from host, it searched for the volumes and couldn't find it ?

Comment: Yes. You removed image, but not all references to it from guests.

Comment: Your question has no question. I tried to answer to question "How guest can still be running well when disk image already removed?"